# What is the difference between mechanics and analog?

Tags: classical-mechanics

What is the difference and the relationship between mechanics and analog/analogue? I have noticed that mechanical things are often considered analog, for example watches.

Note: The difference between digital and analog is clear to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/738881/2451

Comment: Hi user551100. Welcome to Phys.SE. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Comment: Hi, I fixed the problem in the question, but I still can't open it again.

Comment: "Closed. This question is opinion-based. It is not currently accepting answers." Hmm, now the reason for closure is clear. However, the question isn't and wasn't an opinion question, could you reopen the question?

Comment: @Qmechanic Thanks!